# How to inspect a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, sqlite

The first time `db:migrate` is run, it creates a file called `db/development.sqlite3`, which is an SQLite5 database. It is possible to see the structure of the database by opening `db/development.sqlite3` with DB Browser for SQLite. Supposedly, `db/development.sqlite3` is updated every time `db:migrate` is run.

However one possible scenario is that `db:migrate` is run in a topic branch, and a new `db/development.sqlite3` file is created in that branch. Then the topic branch is deleted. The database is modified but the corresponding `db/development.sqlite3` file in the master branch remains unchanged. In this case, `db/development.sqlite3` cannot provide updated information.

Is there any other, more reliable and straightforward way to inspect a database structure both in a development and production environments in any point in time?

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** have your database in git.   Instead, have a development database and a production database (locally), and have a file that is in git (eg config/database.yml) tell Rails which database to **use** for each environment.  The database folders should not live in your Rails application folder, they should be in a standard system location.